# boost::shared_ptr cycle break with weak_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers, circular-dependency, weak

I am currently in a situation like:

```
struct A {  
  shared_ptr<B> b;  
};  
struct B {  
  shared_ptr<A> a;  
};

//...
shared_ptr<A> a(new A());
shared_ptr<B> b(new B());  
a->b(b);
b->a(a);
```

I know this won't work, because the references would continue to point to each other. I've also been told that `weak_ptr` solves this issue.

However, `weak_ptr` has no get or `->` overload. I've heard mentions of 'use `lock()`', but can anyone give code examples of how to do this correctly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Come on now.

http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm

^^^^^ EXAMPLE IS RIGHT THERE ^^^^^^

DAMN!

Comment: -1 While linking to the docs is helpful, SO answers should be useful to future visitors should the link become dead.  This answer provides no information at all except a link.

Comment: Bad attitude towards OP

Answer (score 6):

I think the bigger issue here is one of ambiguous ownership. You'd be better off to decide whether `A` encapsulates `B` or the other way around. If that isn't possible then you're still better off introducing another `class C` that owns both `A` and `B`.

Assuming that `A` owns `B`, you can write:

```
classs B;

classs A
{
private:
    boost::scoped_ptr<B> b_;
public:
    A() : b_(new B()) {}
}

class B
{
private:
    A* a_;
public:
    B(A* a) : a_(a) {}
}
```

And so on. You can even get rid of `scoped_ptr` by making B a local variable or deleting it manually in the destructor.

The [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml) has more to say on this in the section titled "[Smart Pointers](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Smart_Pointers#Smart_Pointers)."

HTH

Comment: +1, I nearly choked on seeing someone reference the Google C++ Style Guide... but for once I agree with them, clear ownership is preferable to sprinkling `shared_ptr` here and there.

Comment: Thank you for the +1! But I'm curious about your view of the Google C++ Style Guide. Is there any particular reason you find it a bit choke-worthy?

Comment: +1 "_the bigger issue here is one of ambiguous ownership_" Yes; you need to consider ownership first, and **only when you understand the relations between your objects** you can choose to use a smart pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the boost reference on [weak_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm)?

```
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(5));
weak_ptr<int> q(p);

// some time later

if(shared_ptr<int> r = q.lock())
{
    // use *r
}
```

The idea is that you lock the `weak_ptr` thereby obtaining a `shared_ptr` which does have the operators.

First check, whether the obtained pointer points to something. A `weak_ptr` does not determine the life-time of the resource, but it lets you check whether the resource has already been destroyed.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>

struct B;

struct A
{
    boost::weak_ptr< B > b;
};

struct B
{
    boost::weak_ptr< A > a;
};

int
main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<A> a(new A());
    boost::shared_ptr<B> b(new B());
    a->b = b;
    b->a = a; 
    boost::shared_ptr<A> another_a( b->a.lock() );
}
```

you can promote a `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` using `weak_ptr::lock`.